# How to sample from the distribution of the difference between two dependent mixture models

Tags: distributions, sampling, independence, mixture-distribution

How to sample from the distribution of the difference between two dependent mixture models

I have two distributions that represent a value before and after an event.

Each of these distributions is comprised of a mixture of normal distributions, so I have *n* means, *n* standard deviations, and *n* proportions for each of the two mixtures.

**I would like to define the distribution that represents the difference between the after and before distributions.**

From domain knowledge I know that before and after aren't independent, i.e. if the before value is at the upper end of it's distribution, the after value is likely to be at the upper end of it's distribution. But I don't have a correlation coefficient, or paired data to infer one. All I have are the parameters for the distributions themselves.

I'm assuming I can't just sample from each distribution and then subtract one from the other to give a sample from the difference distribution and then repeat a large number of times, since they are not independent?

How can I go about generating this difference distribution?

I have looked at numerous answers for summing dependent distributions but they seem to rely on a covariance term, which I don't have. I have also looked into copulas but again that seems to require a covariance matrix. Any guidance about how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: `I'm assuming I can't just sample from each distribution and then subtract one from the other to give a sample from the difference distribution and then repeat a large number of times, since they are not independent?`

So am I wrong in thinking the above?  Can I just subtract samples from each distribution?

Comment: I skipped the dependence remark. But if this dependence is not available to the experimenter, simulation becomes impossible.